# SmartWatch and Smart Wireless Headset Pro app on the market

Tags: sony, headset, sony-smartwatch

I extended my SmartWatch app to work also on the Smart Wireless Headset Pro.

In the developer documentation I read that the SmartWatch apps on Google Play should have a description that ends with: LiveWare™ extension for SmartWatch, while the Smart Wireless Headset Pro apps should have description that ends with: LiveWare™ extension for Smart Wireless Headset pro.

Since my description has only one ending, how should I properly mark my app to be discovered both as an extension for the SmartWatch and the Smart Wireless Headset Pro?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add both strings to your description, e.g. as in the [Facebook extension](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.extension.facebook) example.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I did. I guess the order in which they are listed is irrelevant.